# login with forms doesn't work

Tags: django, authentication

so I'm making a login page with forms, the problem is it doesn't work :D

this is my form

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
        class Meta:

    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'password',]
```

my views.py

```
def user_login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            username = login_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = login_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('restricted')
    else:
       login_form = UserForm()
return render(request, 'userlogin.html', {'login_form': login_form})
```

and my html

```
<h2>Login</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ login_form.username }}
      <br>
      {{ login_form.password }}
      <br>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
```

the restricted is a html that checks which user is logged in. and it works fine 
i'm not sure why it isn't working cuz it keeps redirecting me to the loginuser.html page instead of redirecting me to restricted page which only appears if a user is logged in.

Comment: Please define what `does not work` mean. Add an error stacktrace.

Comment: no error it just doesn't can't authenticate

Comment: did you redirected after `POST` action? show you html template please

Comment: sry i didn't understand what u mean my html template file is up there. and I dont get redirected to my restricted page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add block with form errors to your template

```
<h2>Login</h2>
  <form method="post">
<!-- form errors -->
{% if login_form.errors %}
    {% for field in login_form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in login_form.non_field_errors %}
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<!-- form errors -->
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ login_form.username }}
      <br>
      {{ login_form.password }}
      <br>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: added this, nth happened.

Comment: ssory, i use default form in template, but you use `login_form`, now fixed try new version

Comment: "A user with that username already exists." it's the error i guess. why should i get this? I'm not making a new user

Comment: damnnn it's because of the inheritance I'm using I shouldn't inherit from ModelForm cuz it wants to make new user. tnx m8

Comment: yes, you are right, you can use form the second answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to add more details but here is a step by step guide to login users:

`forms.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model


User = get_user_model()

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()

def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
    password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
    user_obj = User.objects.filter(username=username).first()
    if not user_obj:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid credentials")
    else:
        if not user_obj.check_password(password):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid credentials")
    return super(LoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

and in your `views.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
from .forms import LoginForm # or where you have the LoginForm

User = get_user_model()

def user_login(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            if form.is_valid():
                username_ = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                user_obj = User.objects.get(username__iexact=username_)
                login(request, user_obj)
                return #something
            else:
                # show an error or etc
                ...
        else:
            # user is authenticated before and he is in.
            ...
```

and your `template.html`:

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <hr>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <hr>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

**Note:**
you can use django to render the form but you need to make some changes on form fields like password (adding `PasswordInput` widget)